# App Freezes After Being in Background or Device Idle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

After my app goes into the background or the device is idle for a period of time, when I reopen the app, it appears frozen and unresponsive.
There are no suspicious errors shown in Logcat.
The only way to use it normally again is to remove the app from the multitasking screen and reopen it.
Can anyone tell me what might be causing this? Thank you

Comment: If anybody can tell you what is causing this, then this might be [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat). Make sure to check in `onCreate()` `if (savedInstanceState == null) { ... }` which is the most common culprit.

Comment: @MartinZeitler But the problem occurs when onResume() is called, restarting the app in onCreate() works fine.

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?